# Is there any reason why the pseudoelements ::after and ::before don't work in Foundation?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, pseudo-element, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using Foundation 6 for Sites to create a responsive site. 
I failed to use pseudoelements ::after and ::before (I didn't forget about the content property).
My browser code inspector shows no pseudoelements and they are not implemented on the page.

Any ideas why it has happened and how to deal with it?
May it be a trouble with sass?

Comment: Hi, please provide the code which does not work. It works for me here: https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/xegbaQ

Comment: Here it is --> p::after {
                       content: "";
                       position: absolute;
                      width: 0;
                      height: 0;
                      left: rem-calc(-24);
                      top: rem-calc(33);
                      border: rem-calc(2.5) solid;
                      border-color: transparent $body-background transparent 
                      transparent;
            }

Comment: Gosh! It works! Thank you very mucn.

Answer (score 0):

I use them all the time :)

You said you made sure you include the `content: ''` property inside the psuedo element, so that's good.

If the component is a Foundation CSS component and that element already uses a psuedo element, you can find it using the browser's inspector and see what CSS is targeting it.

Example:

```
.notification-reward {
  align-items: baseline;
  animation: jellyIn 1s;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -58%;

  &::after {
    color: $primary-light;
    content: attr(data-earned-points);
    font-size: $stat-font-size;
    font-weight: 700;
    left: 4.3625rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
  }

  &::before {
    color: $primary-light;
    content: '+';
    font-size: rem-calc(44);
    font-weight: 700;
    left: rem-calc(40);
    position: relative;
    top: -1.6525rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I remembered about content but forgot about &. My huge fault.